# Sprite tint with SpriteBatch.setColor

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx

Why this code doesn't work?
The buttons should be green, but they remain white.
Code works perfect, if i use Textures instead of Sprites.

```
game.interface_batch.begin();
...
game.interface_batch.setColor(0.596f, 0.984f, 0.596f, 1.0f);
exit_button_sprite.draw(game.interface_batch);
play_button_sprite.draw(game.interface_batch);
settings_button_sprite.draw(game.interface_batch);
game.interface_batch.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
...
game.interface_batch.end();
```

How to change the color of multiple Sprites?
Code like this is really heavy for more than 3 sprites:

```
exit_button_sprite.setColor(0.596f, 0.984f, 0.596f, 1.0f);
play_button_sprite.setColor(0.596f, 0.984f, 0.596f, 1.0f);
settings_button_sprite.setColor(0.596f, 0.984f, 0.596f, 1.0f);
exit_button_sprite.draw(game.interface_batch);
play_button_sprite.draw(game.interface_batch);
settings_button_sprite.draw(game.interface_batch);
```

Comment: i know, but why is the first case not working? it would be much more convenient. And about the second case, even if I create a variable, the code will remain heavy.

Comment: or tell me how to get texture from sprite, because I'm getting my sprite from TextureRegion from TextureAtlas and getTexture() not working correctly

Comment: I don't recommend using the Sprite class whatsoever. It is slightly optimized at the expense of conflating asset data with position/size data. The reason it doesn't work as you described is that it holds its own color data and ignores the SpriteBatch color parameter, by design. Just use TextureRegion.